# docker-machine and kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, docker-machine

I've been using Docker for some time now, but I'm new to Kubernetes. One tool that I have always relied on is *docker-machine*, which was particularly useful to me when I wanted to create a new node in aws to be integrated in my swarm, e.g.

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-open-port 8000 --amazonec2-instance-type <instance-type> --amazonec2-region <region> --amazonec2-zone <zone>  --amazonec2-subnet-id <subnet> --amazonec2-vpc-id <vpc-id> --amazonec2-userdata <setup.sh> --amazonec2-use-private-address=true <node_name>
```

this command creates a new node yielding a Docker installation and other Docker-related utilities.

I am trying to do the same for Kubernetes but the above-mentioned command does not install Kubernetes tools. I suppose that I can still this command and include Kubernetes installation commands in a script given as argument under the  --amazonec2-userdata, but still I wonder if there is a "docker-machine equivalent" for Kubernetes? In line with this, another question is whether docker-machine is appropriate at all to create a Kubernetes cluster on aws?

If **no** is the answer to both questions, then what is the appropriate approach to achieve the same goal?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want is here in this link: [how to add an node to my kops cluster? (node in here is my external instance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248179/how-to-add-an-node-to-my-kops-cluster-node-in-here-is-my-external-instance)

In K8s we have the config file where you set some vars like region, subnets, image, etc, since you have all set up you can just adjust the `desire` values and apply it the new config to your cluster.