# Kops - unable to bound to storage class using pvc

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-pvc

I am trying to deploy a WordPress site with MySQL database using `kops`. When I run these YAML files the PVC is in `pending` state and doesn't create the volume on ebs. I first thought it was because of the availability zone in the storage YAML file but I have tried all the possible combinations but no luck.

Storage class

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2 
  zone: us-east-2a
  iopsPerGB: "10"
reclaimPolicy: Delete
allowVolumeExpansion: false
```

Persistent volume claim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: wp-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: wordpress:4.8-apache
        name: wordpress
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: wordpress-mysql
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          value: 123a
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: wordpresss
        volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wp-pv-claim
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: frontend
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30007 
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

I am creating a cluster using this command:

```
kops create cluster \
--node-count=1 \
--node-size=t2.micro \
--master-size=t2.small \
--zones=us-east-2a \
--name=${KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

Comment: Did the same issue occurs, if you will use bigger size master like `--master-size t2.large` when creating cluster?

Comment: If I use us-east-2a as the zone it work fine with mysql pvc but not with wordpress pvc. I haven't tried with t2.large. Secondly, I am using nodeport as a service in wordpress (just stating it as it might have something to do with it too)

Comment: Service shouldnt affect. Could you share your YAMLs? Maybe somewhere is a typo or your cluster dont have enough resources? Also what you have when you use `kubectl describe pvc wp-pv-claim`, Im curious abut this pending state. As for quick test, if you would remove mysql pv/pvc and create for wordpress? Will pv and pvc be created?

Comment: I will share the wordpress complete file, as far as my understanding there is something wrong with the storage file as when I remove the storage file and run it locally pvc actually works. If storage class zone is set to `us-east-2b`  for wordpress and `us-east-2a` for mysql the volumn bound but then wordpress pod go to `pending` state while mysql pod is healthy

Comment: @PjoterS I have added service and deployment yaml files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected in my first comment, you don't have enough resocurces to run `mysql` and `wordpress`.

If you will check [Amazon instance types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t2/) you will see that `t2.nano` and `t2.small` have quite low resources.

```
Name    vCPUs   RAM (GiB)   
t2.nano     1   0.5     
t2.small    1   2.0
```

Also as you mention in your last comment:

**mysql the volumn bound but then wordpress pod go to pending state while mysql pod is healthy**

It's because cluster do not have enough resources to start pod.

If you will use `kubectl describe pod <wordpress-pod-name>` you would get output similar to:

```
Warning FailedScheduling 4s (x4 over 92s) default-scheduler 0/2 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu, 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

Cluster with that amount of resources won't be able to run `wordpress` and `mysql`. Please keep in mind that also kubernetes default pods are running, to check which one, you can run `kubectl get pods -A`.

Solution:

- Create new kops cluster using instance `t2.large` with more resources
- Add node to your kops cluster. You can check [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248179/how-to-add-an-node-to-my-kops-cluster-node-in-here-is-my-external-instance)